# External Sort GC Overhead

Tags: java, sorting, external-sorting

I am writing an external sort to sort a large 2 gig file on disk

I first split the file into chunks that fit into memory and sort each one individually, and rewrite them back to disk. However, during this process I am getting GC Memory overhead exception in String.Split method in function geModel. Below is my code.

```
private static List<Model> getModel(String file, long lineCount, final long readSize) {
    List<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<Model>();
    long read = 0L;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        //Skip lineCount lines;
        for (long i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
            br.readLine();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            read += line.length();
            if (read > readSize)
                break;
            String[] split = line.split("\t");
            String curvature = (split.length >= 7) ? split[6] : "";
            String heading = (split.length >= 8) ? split[7] : "";
            String slope = (split.length == 9) ? split[8] : "";

            modelList.add(new Model(split[0], split[1], split[2], split[3], split[4], split[5], curvature, heading, slope));
        }   
        br.close();
        return modelList;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private static void split(String inputDir, String inputFile, String outputDir, final long readSize) throws IOException {
    long lineCount = 0L;
    int count = 0;
    int writeSize = 100000;
    System.out.println("Reading...");
    List<Model> curModel = getModel(inputDir + inputFile, lineCount, readSize);
    System.out.println("Reading Complete");
    while (curModel.size() > 0) {
        lineCount += curModel.size();
        System.out.println("Sorting...");
        curModel.sort(new Comparator<Model>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Model arg0, Model arg1) {
                return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Sorting Complete");
        System.out.println("Writing...");
        writeFile(curModel, outputDir + inputFile + count, writeSize);
        System.out.println("Writing Complete");
        count++;
        System.out.println("Reading...");
        curModel = getModel(inputDir + inputFile, lineCount, readSize);
        System.out.println("Reading Complete");
    }
}
```

It makes it through one pass and sorts ~250 MB of data from the file. However, on the second pass it throws GC Memory Overhead exception on String.split function. I do not want to use external libraries, I want to learn this on my own. The sorting and splitting works, but I cannot understand why the GC is throwing memory overhead exception on string.split function.

Comment: can you post what kind of data each line has. And as Bill mentioned in his answer you have multiple ways to debug or profile this. One thing I do not understand is what is Model object/class doing. Based on my understanding. You file seems to be words separated by tab, and you are most probably having only 8 words in each line.

Comment: You need to look up how to do external sorting properly. This isn't it. You need to do distribution of initial runs by replacement selection, followed by a polyphase or balanced merge.

Comment: @EJP I understand there are further ways to optimize this sort. But, this sort does give me sorted data. The output is fine, but may not be as optimal as an actual external sort that has multiple merge phases. This one only has one merge phase, which has many more IO operations than an optimized merge sort would have. Would you agree with what I wrote?

Comment: I guess it would be hard to tell since I dont have the merge portion posted in the question. Basically I grab an amount of the data that will fit into memory, sort it, write it to a new file, repeat this process for the entire file. Once the splitting is complete, I run my merge portion which then does a k-way-merge through all of my split files sorting them like a merge in a merge sort would until we have one large sorted file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure just what is causing the exception--manipulating large strings, in particular cutting and splicing them, is a huge memory/gc issue.  StringBuilder can help, but in general you may have to take more direct control over the process.

To figure out more you probably want to run a profiler with your app.  There is one built into the JDK (VisualVM) that is functional.  It will show you what objects Java is holding on to... because of the nature of strings it's possible that you are holding onto a lot of redundant character array data.

Personally I'd try a completely different approach, for instance, what if you sorted the entire file in memory by loading the first 10(?) sortable characters of each line into an array along with the file location they were read from, sort the array and resolve any ties by loading more (the rest?) of those lines that were identical.

If you did something like that then you should be able to seek to each line and copy it to the destination file without ever caching more than one line in memory and only reading through the source file twice.

I suppose you could manufacture a file that would fail if all the strings were identical until the last couple characters, so if that ever became an issue you might have to be able to flush the full strings you've cached (there is a java memory reference object made to automatically do this for you, it's not particularly hard)

Answer (score 0):

Based on how I read your implementation **readSize** only makes sure that you get first block X size. You are not reading 2nd block or 3rd block. Hence its not actually complete external sort.

```
 read += line.length();
        if (read > readSize)
            break;
String[] split = line.split("\t");
```

even though you are splitting each line you seem to be using only first 9 characters. And then checking no of words in each line. This means your data is not uniform.